# I have just started a PhD and my university expects me to present a conference paper, but I don't know what's expected

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I have started doing a Ph.D recently. I am working on "Generalized inverse of Matrices and its Applications". And my university is asking me to present a paper in a conference, at least to show the progress on the work.

As you know, getting a result for a paper (within six months of starting a Ph.D) is not that easy, without understanding the basics properly.

Now I have to present a paper or a poster in a conference or in a workshop.

I don't know about the standard of conference papers or what is expected. What is expected of a conference paper?

Comment: Can you give me reason for the downvote??

Comment: Is it explicitly written somewhere in the rules that you have to publish something in the first six months itself? i.e. is it a rule, or a convention?

Comment: It is not a rule.. but my guide and doctral commity is forcing to do that..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a conference paper is expected to be original research, similar to a normal publication.  However, the results often don't have to be as extensive or polished as they would be for a full publication.  Preliminary findings are often appropriate, for example.  Depending on the conference, you might be able to publish about research plans or a particular methodological issue that arose in your research.

Depending on the conference, the standards might be quite high (requiring something equivalent to a typical peer-reviewed journal publication) or the bar might be a lot lower.

Ultimately, this comes down to standards in your field of study and the requirements of the particular conference.

To find what is acceptable, you should:

- **Read the conference's call for papers** and make sure the type of content and subject matter are within what is being requested.
- **Talk to experts in your field** about what is appropriate to publish. If you know anyone who has attended the same conference in the past, that would be especially helpful.
- **Look at past accepted papers**.  These are typically published, so you can find examples of what was considered acceptable in the past.

As a PhD student, you should certainly start with discussing this with your adviser.  Your adviser is an expert in the field who has a particular interest in your development, and they can also inform about the expectations of your university.

Comment: I think "Talk to your advisor" needs to be on this list... presumably your advisor is both an expert in the field and also very familiar with your work, and so is better positioned than anyone to help.

Comment: @ff524, agreed.  However, it wasn't clear that the OP was a PhD student at time of answering.

Comment: If the OP was not a PhD student and/or did not have an advisor, first item on the list should be "Find an advisor" :)